# the loop (for) iteration throguh an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I made a simple program that works as a phone book. When a user types a name in the input field, the program searches an array of objects containing names and numbers and, if it finds the name, outputs name and phone number. If the name is not found, it lets the user know. However, when I type a name the result stays the same 'Name not found', even though the array contains given name. Here is the code

```
const phonebook = [
 {name : `Adam`, number : `001`},
 {name : `Anna`, number : `002`},
]

const input = document.querySelector('input');
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const para = document.querySelector('p');

btn.addEventListener ('click', function () {
 let searchName = input.value.toLowerCase();
 input.value = '';
 input.focus();

 for (let i = 0; i < phonebook.length; i++) {
     if (searchName === phonebook[i].name) {
         para.textContent = `${phonebook[i].name's number is ${phonebook[i].number}.`;
         break;
     } else {
         para.textContent = `Name not found in phonebook';
     }
}
});
```

Comment: your code is fine. The names start with capital letters yet you convert the input to lower case. Please debug your code before ask?

Comment: Make sure you lowercase phonebook[i].name as well for the comparison to work. You have typos as well, check that "cont" instead of "const". Just so more people can try your code instead of assuming it runs.

Comment: Fix your typos. Remove/add `.toLowerCase()`. Your code is running fine.

Comment: The code doesn't work if the `phonebook` is empty, but I can't see it misbehaving in the way you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para.textContent = `${phonebook[i].name} (<- missing closing bracket) 's number is ${phonebook[i].number}.`;

- You are missing a losing curlybrackets there.
- You are transforming input to lowercase but you data source includes capital letters. Transform both to lower then.

If it's not a specific case where you need for loop and onClick event, I would recommend:

- Using keydown eventlistener
- Using Filter

```
    btn.addEventListener(keydown, function {
            phonebook.filter((x) => x.name === input.value)
             if (phonebook.length === 1) {para.textContent = `${phonebook[0].name}'s number is ${phonebook[0].number}`}
            else if (phonebook.length === 0) {para.textContent = "not found"};
            })
```

Or something similar. So your code are more responsive in terms of giving feedback to the user.